# How to separate digits in a string into four character blocks

Tags: javascript

Given that ccnum is a 16-character string containing only numbers (credit card number), I want to format the string nicely with 4 digits at a time, separated by spaces. I tried this:

```
ccnum=ccnum.substring(0, 4)+' '+
      ccnum.substring(4, 4)+' '+
      ccnum.substring(8, 4)+' '+
      ccnum.substring(12, 4);
```

But I get unpredictable results, such as:

```
12341234 1234 1234
1234 1234 12341234
```

Not sure why?

Comment: Your substring is not [syntactically correct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) - you have coded it like [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: `substring` function splits a string and assigned to the same variable , check my answer for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's [`match()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) together with a simple regular expression to get what you need.

> The match() method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.

```
var str = "1234123412341324";
var results = str.match(/\d{4}/g);
var final_cc_str = results.join(" ");
```

The regular expression `/\d{4}/g` is searching for digit characters (`\d`). Four of them (`{4}`). And it wants to find *all* matches so it uses the `g` flag for a global search.

After that I'm using the [`join()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate each of the matched elements with a space character as the delimiter.

> The join() method joins all elements of an array into a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ccnum = '1111222233334444';

ccnum.match(/.{1,4}/g);
```

Result

```
["1111", "2222", "3333", "4444"]
```

Comment: Assuming that this is user provided data, I don't think it would be wise to assume that the string only contains numbers... Unless there is some other validation method that was not mentioned by the OP.

Comment: If you know that you are searching for digits, I would say that it'll always be better to explicitly define what you want to search for.

Comment: Since credit card number is 16 digits which are numbers.

Comment: Yes, I am doing other validation to ensure 16 digits before I get to this step.

Answer (score 2):

You have confused

[substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

> The substring() method returns a subset of a string between one index and another, or through the end of the string.
>
> Syntax `str.substring(indexA[, indexB])`

```js
ccnum=ccnum.substring(0, 4)+' '+
      ccnum.substring(4, 8)+' '+
      ccnum.substring(8, 12)+' '+
      ccnum.substring(12, 16);
```

with  [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

> The substr() method returns the characters in a string beginning at the specified location through the specified number of characters.
>
> Syntax `str.substr(start[, length])`

```js
ccnum=ccnum.substr(0, 4)+' '+
      ccnum.substr(4, 4)+' '+
      ccnum.substr(8, 4)+' '+
      ccnum.substr(12, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr` instead of `substring`

Try This

```
var ccnum = '123456789123456';

ccnum.substr(0, 4)+' '+ccnum.substr(4, 4)+' '+ccnum.substr(8, 4)+' '+ccnum.substr(12, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JfWN7/)

```
"1111222233334444".match(/.{1,4}/g).join(" ");
```